# ReportViewer textbox moves unexpectedly

Tags: c#, reportviewer, iif

I'm using ReportViewer at my work and I've run into a problem I can't solve. This particular report is one that has a section that's visibility is determined by checking a field:

```
=IIf(Fields!TRREQUEST_BK_STATUS_CD.Value.ToString() <> "DELETE", True, False)
```

This isn't where the problem is happening though. Above this section, there are two sets of textboxes. One that uses the TRREQUEST_BK_STATUS_CD and displays either DELETE or APPRVD, and another set that displays a book ID. The weird thing that's happening, is that which ever set of textboxes are on the right hand side get shifted to the left a few notches on an APPRVD report. On the DELETE reports it remains where it's supposed to be.

In all the other reports, we haven't had any problems like this. That's why I'm assuming it's some weird bug with the IIf statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be looking at your expression which looks reasonable, that its a layout issue rather than code.

Try setting widths a little wider than they are currently on the textboxes and try lining up the heights/locations (will have to be manual rather than dragging them around) of items on the left and right as the rendering has to use layout structures to position your items.

Is it WebForms or WinForms?

Comment: WinForms. We've kind of moved on from this project, but I think our temporary solution was to swap the text boxes. We'll undoubtedly be coming back to these reports in a month or two and I'll be doing some more testing with them then. Thanks for the response though! If I remember I'll update this question with any solutions we come across.

Comment: Yup, I noticed after posting the answer that this was an old question! :(